# Interfacing Delta PLC and Arduino (Logic Signals)

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, level-shifting, logic-level, plc

I am trying to connect a Delta PLC (DVP-10SX) to an Arduino UNO. What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to exchange Logic signals between both the PLC which has a logic level of 0-24V and Arduino 0-5V noting that bidirectional transmission/receiving of logic signals is a must, so an Arduino can send signals to the PLC and vise-versa. I searched Google but couldn't find a way or module allowing this kind of communication.

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:
Edited for a better description of the issue.

Comment: Logic signals and communication are not the same thing. Please edit to clarify. Are you hoping to do bidirectional communication on the one wire?

Comment: @Transistor, Thank you! I edited my question. Answering your question, no, I am trying to link I/O of the PLC and an Arduino.

Comment: Right, so you are looking for uni-directional signals but in both directions. Bi-directional suggests that data must travel both ways along one wire. You might consider the [Finder Arduino Pro](https://www.findernet.com/en/usa/news/finder-opta-the-unique-new-programmable-logic-relay/) which is Arduino based but uses industrial grade input and output, 24 V compatible. It will be industrial-hardened and much more reliable than a hobby board with little quality assurance. Do the right thing if this is a commercial application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to send logic signals between devices of different logic voltages is to use optoisolators (also called optocouplers). When specifying an optoisolator, you need to look at the range of input and output voltages it can accept.

As an example, take a look at the different optoisolators that are available from [Automation Direct](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/relays_-z-_timers/optocoupler_relays). Other manufacturers have even more selection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to link inputs and outputs of the 2 devices?

#### PLC Output to Arduino input

The easiest is to use a PLC with NPN outputs, link the common of the PLC output to Arduino ground, and set the arduino pin to *input_pullup*.

- When the PLC output is **OFF** the output goes to *high impedance* (which means it behaves similarly to being disconnected). The arduino input gets pulled up by default, and reads high.
- When the PLC output is **ON** it pulls to ground (not 24V). This overcomes the pullup resisitor of the arduino and the input reads low.

#### Arduino output to PLC input

This is a little more difficult because the input of the Delta DVP switches on at around 10v. You only have 5v on an arduino, so you'll need a transistor. I have taken the liberty of drawing you a circuit using an NPN transistor (Q1 in the diagram).

- When the arduino output is **OFF**, the transistor blocks current, and voltage at the PLC input rises to 24v.
- When the arduino output is **ON**, the transistor turns on, current flows, and voltage at the PLC input drops to 0v.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNauD2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### PLC Output to Arduino input

TI have a range of [Multi-switch detection interface (MSDI) ICs](https://www.ti.com/interface/multi-switch-detection-interface/products.html) devices which are designed to read 24 V input voltages and convert to a reduced output range of 0-5 V.

E.g. the description in the [SN65HVS883](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvs883.pdf) datasheet contains:

> The SN65HVS883 is a 24-V, eight-channel, digital- input serializer for high-channel density digital input modules of PC and PLC-based systems in industrial automation.

And the *Simplified I/O Structure* from the datasheet:

[image]

Having an interface IC designed to level-shift PLC input voltages could simplify the design over using discrete level shifting, but for the example of SN65HVS883 does mean the Arduino UNO would need to run the shift register to read all inputs. Not sure if that would be a benefit, or disadvantage, for the design.

### Arduino output to PLC input

From an initial search couldn't seem to find any interface ICs designed to level shift the other direction from 5 V to 24 V.

Answer (score 0):

**Inputs**

PLC have their IO following a standard, IEC 61131-2, to ensure vendors use the same voltage levels and there is decent noise immunity. For example the "On" and "Off" voltage and currents are specified. The current is reasonably high to ensure coupled noise will not trigger an input.

[image]

You can approximate this with some [resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320159/12v-input-on-microcontroller-pin/320170#320170). Not exactly though.
However if you calculate the power these resistors will dissipate it's somewhat high and takes a board space. Especially at 30V. (24V +25% from a battery charger for example)
To combat this vendors have made IC's that solve this current sink problem.
For example: the SN65HVS883 suggested by Chester Gillon, or the ST CLT03-1SC3.

**Outputs**
To output to 24V you also need to comply to this standard, but the other way around. If you only intend to source logic inputs, you can use a pull-down method as suggested by Micheal.
But if you want to isolate the signal with a relay, as often in industry, you need to drive this relay. Which is a small current (~30mA)

For this you can use a High Side switch, for example Infineon BTS4140N.
These category of devices are very robust.

If you do not have 24V on your arduino side, you must use the sinking output model with external resistor. You can also use sinking outputs to drive relays.
*Make sure you add transient and back-emf protection.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKcNkv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>